# API Management Premium - Simulate DR fail over

Tags: azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I was wondering how it would be possible to simulate an Azure region failure or some other APIM related component failure to test whether APIM Premium would automatically routes the gateway to secondary region during a primary region failure?
I have tested that this is working from a location perspective, ie requests made from the secondary region definitely go through the secondary gateway but not sure how to simulate a fail over as such...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 Update

Additional locations now can be controlled to disable gateway traffic. See `disableGateway` property in APIM's REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/api-management-service/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#additionallocation. Can also be controlled via Azure Portal. Once disabled traffix will be turned off from that location.
Primary region though cannot be controlled still.

#### Original answer

Premium APIM runs Traffic Manager with performance profile in front of region specific services. For DR to happen one of those services has to go down. Provided that customer has no direct access to these services it is not possible to simulate DR by customer alone. You could contact support and ask them to bring one of the regions down temporarily.

Comment: are you kidding?